# How to increase QSPI flash clock frequncy in Zynq ZC702

Tags: xilinx, qspi

I am working on Zynq ZC702 board. The board has a QSPI flash.  I want to increase the clock frequency of QSPI, so that I can read/write at a much faster rate.

The closest I found is this :

[EDK-14.3,Zynq-7000 - What is the default QSPI interface clock frequency used in the FSBL and how do I speed it up?
Search](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/51782.html)

But reading this it is not clear to me exactly where do I make changes, DIV/8 to DIV 8 etc, are these parameters in FSB.elf file? I remember I was not able to open this file, as it is a binary file.

Any idea how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the xilinx answer

[**AR# 46880** Zynq-7000 Example Design - Linear QSPI Performance (Max Effective Throughput)](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/46880.html)

> This example design shows how to achieve QSPI (in Linear Mode) Maximum
>   Effective Throughput with a 100 MHz SPI clock.

There you can get the maximum throughput with the QSPI interface.

You can find the source code for the project here:
[xdmaps_example_w_intr_14_2.c](http://www.xilinx.com/Attachment/xdmaps_example_w_intr_14_2.c)